# Graph theory , a problem

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> In a non-empty graph, every two vertices with the same degree do not
>   have a common neighbor. Prove that there exists a vertex with degree
>   one in this graph.

Comment: Consider a graph with $7$ isolated vertices (each of degree zero). Certainly, every two vertices with the same degree (in other words, all the vertices) do not have a common neighbour (since no vertex has a neighbour). Yet there is no vertex with degree one.

Comment: The graph is not empty.I have edited the statement

Comment: Adriano's comment still holds. You might want to edit your post to say non-empty, connected.

Comment: How?In his example the graph has no edges , it is empty

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'm apparently too tired to be here right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v$ be a vertex of maximal degree $k$.
The $k$ neighbours of $v$ must all have a different degree, otherwise $v$
itself is common neighbour of two vertices with the same degree.
So the neighbours of $v$ must have degrees $1,2,\ldots,k$.
This exhibits a vertex of degree 1.